# popular flame icon does not display in CKAN

Tags: python, css, less, jinja2, ckan

**Scenario:**

I'm using default popular function in helpers.py. However, it will not display the icon after a package/resource which has more than 10 views. How I set the popular function in my `resource_item.html` template is as follow:

```
{{ h.popular('views', res.tracking_summary.total, min=10) }}
```

I've also checked out the snippet which will be rendered by `h.popular`:

```
{% if number >= min %}
<span class="popular ckan-icon ckan-icon-flame" title="{{ title.format(number=number) }}" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">{{ _('Popular') }}</span>
{% endif %}
```

It can only render the text 'Popular'. I tried to remove the text, and it seems like CKAN can not get the `ckan-icon-flame`. Then I checked `icons.less`, and `ckan-icon-flame` has been defined.

**Additional Information:**

I implemented a customized tracking tool. So I didn't enable the `ckan.tracking_enabled` in my `ckan.ini` file. I wonder if this change is related to load the icon correctly. But based on my readings of the code, I didn't find there's any condition related to the render of icon.

**More Information:**

variable.less:

```
@imagePath: "../../../base/images";
@spritePath: "@{imagePath}/sprite-ckan-icons.png";
```

icons.less:

```
.ckan-icon {
    //.ie7-restore-right-whitespace;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background-image: url("@{imagePath}/sprite-ckan-icons.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 16px 16px;
}

.ckan-icon-background-position(@offset,
@size) {
    @w: "@{size}X";
    @h: "@{size}Y";
    @x: "@{size}OffsetX";
    @y: "@{size}OffsetY";
    width: @@w;
    height: @@h;
    background-position: (@@x * @offset) @@y;
}

.ckan-icon-flame {
    .ckan-icon-background-position(2,
    "medium")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CKAN has its default css. It also allows developers to customize the default css. My problem is caused by overwrite. My new style sheet will completely overwrite the default css instead of adding them in the default file. For more detailed discussion, you can refer to the issues here: https://github.com/ckan/ckan/issues/4542